# Conditional flex in Angular material

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

Given the bootstrap layout definition

```
ng-class="{'col-sm-6':vm.data.mode === 'ADD', 'col-sm-3': vm.data.mode === 'EDIT'}"
```

What's the angular material equivalent? (To set flex="50" if vm.data.mode === 'ADD' and set flex="25" if vm.data.mode === 'EDIT')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try below.

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div flex-gt-sm="{{vm.data.mode === 'ADD' ? 50: 25}}"></div>
  <div flex-gt-sm="{{vm.data.mode === 'ADD' ? 50: 25}}"></div>
  <div flex-gt-sm="{{vm.data.mode === 'ADD' ? 50: 25}}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Looking for something like this.